# Efficiently drawing and animating thousands of rectangles

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, animation, drawing

What I am trying to do is to have many small rectangles on the screen (up to several thousand) which move randomly.

I have the mechanics behind this figured out (in terms of determining the coordinates for the movement), but I can't figure out the best way to draw the shapes or model their movement.

A couple strategies I have tried have been, first, to subclass NSView (this is on the Mac) and create thousands of these. I then change their drawRect: function in order to draw a square inside of themselves. Then it is pretty simple to just change their locations to move them around. However, with several thousand allocated instances of these, performance is obviously terrible.

I tried a less object-oriented route also, just using NSRectFill to draw the thousands of rectangles. However, I had trouble implementing the movement I needed with this, though it was blazing fast.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could successfully create this animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Layers and Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) are the best approach for the platform.

Comment: I tried that solution with thousand `CALayers` and it worked. But with ten thousand `CALayers` or more, it begins to lag. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @OathComrade It's impossible to say without a LOT more detail. How are the layers created? How are they maintained? What is their caching policy? Etc. Post your problem and all relevant information (this includes code) as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Several thousand rectangles may be too much for CoreAnimation.  You should consider using OpenGL.

Comment: Maybe not. The original demo for Core Animation involved 850 rectangles—*playing video clips*. http://youtube.com/watch?v=pyd8O-2mkgk “Several thousand” *static* rectangles, on two-to-four-years-newer GPUs, should be no problem. Of course, the one sure way to find out would be to try it.

Comment: Your average iOS UI screen easily has several hundred `CALayers` on it at any one time; each `UIView` has its own `CALayer`, and `UIViews` are used *all over the place*.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: And that's on the iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad. The Mac, which the questioner is targeting, has a far beefier GPU and more and beefier CPUs.

Comment: I've definitely been able to animate over 5000 layers at once on a Mac with Core Animation. Since the layers are basically just OpenGL surfaces the performance is excellent.